# Multiple Values from Excel cell to XML

Tags: xml, excel, xsd, schema, thesaurus

I need to turn an Excel file into a very specific XML file for a Microsoft Search Thesaurus.

This is a snippet of the Excel file:
[Excel Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWP09.png)

And this is an example of what the XML needs to look like:
[XML Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl02Q.png)

I am finding it difficult to make the XML file because it has multiple of the same tag (i.e. sub) and Excel does not seem to like a maxOccurs="unbounded" in an XML map nor does it like multiple elements of the same name.

There is also the fact of having multiple values separated by commas in one cell.

This is my current XSD file if it helps:

```html
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="x-schema:tsSchema.xml" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="thesaurus">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="diacritics_sensitive"/>
        <xs:element name="expansion" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="sub" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Clint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is trying this I ended up putting each value I wanted into a separate column with a separate column name. And the each  in the XML file was called , , etc. Then after I made the XML I use VBA to edit the file and replace the  with .

Answer (score -1):

**strong text**You must open an other existant XML file and copy/paste your data

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean by that.